# importing library into java

Tags: java, maven, intellij-14

I am very new to java

I downloaded an open source java project

which has this line of code

```
import sun.swing.SwingUtilities2;
```

I am getting this error

```
Error:(94, 38) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable SwingUtilities2
  location: class org.apache.ctakes.gui.component.SmoothToolTip.SmoothToolTipUI
```

I have downloaded this jar file from here

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsdgstubsjre15jar.htm

I am trying to add it to my project

through going to project structure in IntelliJ and then add library

but I get another error when i click the ok button

[image]

how to import this library in my project ?

Comment: is it a maven project? does it have submodules?

Comment: it is maven project, but not sure what submodules are.

Comment: you need to add maven dependency, instead of manually adding it to intellij libraries

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's like to be a maven project.
if so, why not trying to add the dependency instead of downloading the jar file manually?

try to add:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun/tools -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
    <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
</dependency>
```

to your pom file and then build the project again.
this way maven download it for you automatically.

Comment: how to import these libraries too org.hibernate.SessionFactory / org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper / org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate

Comment: just find them in maven repository sites like: [link](https://mvnrepository.com/), or you can use google to to that.
after finding them add them to your pom.xml file in the project in <dependencies> tag